# How to inform the parent process that I am done

Tags: c, linux

This is a very basic question. The parent process will create some shared memory where it will put two integers in there, then it forked a child which will go to the shared memory and compute the sum of them. All this is fine, but how would the child inform the parent that it's done computing the sum? Do I need to create a pipe between the two processes to do this? or waitpid() is sufficient to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `waitpid` yet, or are you waiting for someone to tell you to try it?

Comment: @paddy Yea, I mentioned waitpid at the end, but I am not sure if it is sufficient, since it seems to me that waitpid() only get called when the child process is terminated. But what if I want the child process to perform more tasks after it computes the sum? In that case, the child needs to inform the parent that it's done computing sum and continue with the rest of the work.

Comment: You didn't mention in your post whether your child process needed to exit or not.  There is a good answer now that should help you.

Comment: I'd consider reworking your algorithm so that `waitpid()` is sufficient. Keeping the child process alive complicates things a bit, probably needlessly if your intent is to reuse the child process. Obviously if you want to preserve some internal state of the process that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your child process is no longer needed after computing the sum of your integers, it can return the sum from main and the parent process can retrieve the result using waitpid. In this case, the child would look something like this:

Child process:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a,b;
    /* read integers a and b from shared memory */

    /* return sum */
    return a + b;
}
```

If the child process is still needed to do further work for the parent, set up a pipe between the child and parent or arrange some other form of IPC to pass info back and forth.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: D'oh! I forgot about the exit values attached to the return value. This first solution stinks -- the parent and child should set up a pipe or IPC to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

If the child exits after writing the sum, then `waitpid()` will suffice. Otherwise, you need some IPC (a mutex/semaphore/pipe) to signal the completion.

Comment: This is exactly what I think I should do. I thought about using status argument in waitpid to indicate the completion of the summation task, but not sure if it can be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

`waitpid()` should be fine for this purpose. Simply fork and in the parent do `waitpid()` and in the child compute the same into the shared memory location and just return and `waitpid()` will unblock and the parent can do whatever it wants with that sum.